# Need semantic markup

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

What is the best semantic and accessible mark up for data like student/employee information.

I have a page where I want to display person information like
name (first+last), address, birthday, phone number, email, website, major, minor, high school, father name, mother name etc.

It is not a tabular data as this is not list of data. this is information about only one person/object/school/company.

It may be presented in one, two or three column mixed layout.
example

```
name
phone number | email | website
------------------------------
section title
major | minor
current gpa | last semester gpa

section title
------------------------------
father | mother
school | college
```

I was thinking about using Div + DL but seems overkill for accessibility.

```
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <dl>
       <dt>Major</dt>
       <dd>Computer Science</dd>
     </dl>

     <dl>
       <dt>Minor</dt>
       <dd>Math</dd>
     </dl>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic markup for such information in HTML, except perhaps when using odd semantics for the word “semantic.” But the data *is* tabular, as it can be organized as a two-column table, with property name in one column, property value in another. Whether you use a table, or a description list, or something else should depend on the acceptability of default rendering and ease of styling.

Using `dl` is wrong by HTML 4 definitions (this is not a list of *definitions*), but HTML 4 is self-contradictory in this issue, and the practical view (and HTML5 view) is that `dl` is just a list of name/value pairs. If you decide to use it, it would probably be simplest to have a single `dl` element, containing several such pairs.

But if the items are to be separated by headings, then it would be best to have heading markup for the headings, and one table or one `dl` element after each of them.

Answer (score 0):

microformats ftw. you can use dl, although i'd use a ul, but it's really prerogative; it makes sense just like using a list makes sense for nearly anything, but it's really your opinion. you can use hcard microformat for the student. for his grades and major....i'm not really sure; i 100% believe and support microformats, but there is some grey areas. you can make your own decisions.. you can use xfn for the parents (rel="parent"), but the major, again, is up to you. ref: http://microformats.org